# How to select files in directory according to date in filename and copy to another folder

Tags: r

I have a set of files with the following names in a folder (tempfiles1):

```
ASC05012019R.DBF
ASC05012019R.NTX
ASC05012019H.DBF
ASC05012019H.NTX
ASC05012019F.DBF
ASC05012019F.NTX
ROS12012019R.DBF
ROS12012019R.NTX
ROS12012019H.DBF
ROS12012019H.NTX
ROS12012019F.DBF
ROS12012019F.NTX
BAL25012019R.DBF
BAL25012019R.NTX
BAL25012019H.DBF
BAL25012019H.NTX
BAL25012019F.DBF
BAL25012019F.NTX
ROK20012019R.DBF
ROK20012019R.NTX
ROK20012019H.DBF
ROK20012019H.NTX
ROK20012019F.DBF
ROK20012019F.NTX
```

Each filename has 3 different letters to begin with, but all are followed by a date in the format ddmmyyyy.

There are other files in the folder (as shown above) like R.NTX, H.NTX or F.NTX and others but I am only looking for the files with extension of "R.DBF", "H.DBF" and "F.DBF".

I wish to select from a date range, say 05012019 to 22012019, and copy all of the R.DBF, H.DBF and F.DBF files to another folder (tempfiles2).

I have been able to specify my folders:

```
current_folder <- "G:/m/HR/tempfiles1"
new_folder <- "G:/m/HR/tempfiles2"
```

and extract the date from each of the file names:

```
list_of_files <- substr(list.files(current_folder, ".DBF"),4,11) 
list_of_files <- as.Date(list_of_files, format= "%d%m%Y")
```

But here is where I'm stuck. I tried using pattern but this returned an invalid pattern argument error:

```
list_of_files1 <- list.files(current_folder, pattern = 2019-01-05)
```

Plus this will only give me one date.

I can copy the files using file.copy, like so:

```
file.copy(file.path(current_folder,list_of_files), new_folder)
```

But I can't figure out how to select the dates.

The end result of the example above using dates between 05012019 to 22012019 would be to have the correct files copied to the folder tempfiles2:

```
ASC05012019R.DBF
ASC05012019H.DBF
ASC05012019F.DBF
ROS12012019R.DBF    
ROS12012019H.DBF    
ROS12012019F.DBF       
ROK20012019R.DBF    
ROK20012019H.DBF    
ROK20012019F.DBF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#Define start and end date to select from files
start_range <- as.Date("05012019", format = "%d%m%Y")
end_range <- as.Date("22012019",  format = "%d%m%Y")

#Get full path of file names to copy
file_path <- list.files(current_folder, ".DBF", full.names = TRUE)

#Get date from the filenames to compare
list_date <- as.Date(substr(list.files(current_folder, ".DBF"),
              4,11), format= "%d%m%Y")

#Select the files which lie in the range of dates
files_to_copy <- file_path[list_date %in% seq(start_range, end_range, by = "1 day")]

#Copy the files
file.copy(files_to_copy, new_folder)
```

Comment: this is great. It does however output "TRUE" in the console for each file copied. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Matt yes, you can wrap it in `invisible` , `invisible(file.copy(files_to_copy, new_folder))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach:

```r
# make some files to work with
files <- c("ASC05012019R.DBF", "ASC05012019R.NTX", "ASC05012019H.DBF", 
           "ASC05012019H.NTX", "ASC05012019F.DBF", "ASC05012019F.NTX", "ROS12012019R.DBF", 
           "ROS12012019R.NTX", "ROS12012019H.DBF", "ROS12012019H.NTX", "ROS12012019F.DBF", 
           "ROS12012019F.NTX", "BAL25012019R.DBF", "BAL25012019R.NTX", "BAL25012019H.DBF", 
           "BAL25012019H.NTX", "BAL25012019F.DBF", "BAL25012019F.NTX", "ROK20012019R.DBF", 
           "ROK20012019R.NTX", "ROK20012019H.DBF", "ROK20012019H.NTX", "ROK20012019F.DBF", 
           "ROK20012019F.NTX")
dir.create('temp')
setwd('temp')
file.create(files)
#>  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [15] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

# use a set in a regex pattern to get files with the right ending
files <- list.files(pattern = '[RHF].DBF$')
files
#>  [1] "ASC05012019F.DBF" "ASC05012019H.DBF" "ASC05012019R.DBF"
#>  [4] "BAL25012019F.DBF" "BAL25012019H.DBF" "BAL25012019R.DBF"
#>  [7] "ROK20012019F.DBF" "ROK20012019H.DBF" "ROK20012019R.DBF"
#> [10] "ROS12012019F.DBF" "ROS12012019H.DBF" "ROS12012019R.DBF"

# extract and parse the dates
file_dates <- as.Date(sub('\\D+(\\d+).*', '\\1', files), '%d%m%Y')
file_dates
#>  [1] "2019-01-05" "2019-01-05" "2019-01-05" "2019-01-25" "2019-01-25"
#>  [6] "2019-01-25" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-12"
#> [11] "2019-01-12" "2019-01-12"

# subset based on the dates
wanted_files <- files[file_dates > as.Date('2019-01-05') & file_dates < as.Date('2019-01-22')]
wanted_files
#> [1] "ROK20012019F.DBF" "ROK20012019H.DBF" "ROK20012019R.DBF"
#> [4] "ROS12012019F.DBF" "ROS12012019H.DBF" "ROS12012019R.DBF"

# make a new directory
new_dir <- 'temp2'
dir.create(new_dir)

# move the files you care about
file.rename(wanted_files, file.path(new_dir, wanted_files))
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

# check that they're there
list.files(new_dir)
#> [1] "ROK20012019F.DBF" "ROK20012019H.DBF" "ROK20012019R.DBF"
#> [4] "ROS12012019F.DBF" "ROS12012019H.DBF" "ROS12012019R.DBF"
```

Comment: I have just seen this so will try it out now.